How to install the noise module
I am trying to get a script to run. I need the noise module to install it.
Running "pip install noise" produces:
Collecting noise
  Using cached noise-1.2.2.zip (132 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: noise
  Building wheel for noise (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for noise (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\noise
      copying .\perlin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\noise
      copying .\shader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\noise
      copying .\shader_noise.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\noise
      copying .\test.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\noise
      copying .\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\noise
      running build_ext
      building 'noise._simplex' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for noise
Failed to build noise
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (noise)`

Try installing Build Tools. Ensure W10 SDK is checked. Install. Run again. Same error.
Try downloading and using prebuilt wheel.
Run "pip install noise-1.2.3-cp312-cp312-win_arm64.whl"
ERROR: noise-1.2.3-cp312-cp312-win_arm64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. 
I am not really a programmer. What can I try next?

I;m not 100% sure , but the prebuilt wheel noise-1.2.3-cp312-cp312-win_arm64.whl seems to be made for arm processor.  Are you on an arm processor based machine  ?
Edit- Given the compilation output above, you would need  a wheel file ending in amd64.whl . amd64 is the standard for 64 bit X86 machines,

check out : https://github.com/caseman/noise

The 2 wheel packages you are trying to install are for very different CPU architectures. The first is for amd64 and the second is arm64. One or the other is definitely not gonna work, simply because you can't be running on a machine that is both.
Since, it seems like you are running on Windows, you probably need an amd64 package.
The first package is also from 2015 (it's coming from here) which may be causing the installation issues.
The second prebuilt is for arm64, which unless you are running on something like a Raspberry Pi, is not gonna work.
There are more up-to-date Perlin noise generator packages out there like perlin-noise.
Since you mentioned you are tying to get an existing script to run, maybe post the code here. It might be easy to modify it to use a different noise package.
